# IRC For Mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

I know there is a "chat" on here but does anyone use IRC? Is this something MY users would enjoy? These days there are multiple clients to connect to IRC via Windows/Linux/Mac and even browser based clients. I am almost always connected to Freenode as I assume many on here are. If someone created a ##Mi-Yodeya channel or something similar, it would give those of us who work online and others who just want to chat with friends a medium to discuss in a moderated way (I understand MY is already moderated but a different way) anyone opposed to it?

Comment: I would definitely use it.

Comment: I opened ##Mi-Yodea on Freenode if anyone wants to connect there. I can make whomever need to be the room owner etc when / if they join. Anyone who wants can access it via browser [here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=##mi-yodea)

Comment: @Yossi, it may be worth spelling the channel the way the site name is spelled, `##Mi-Yodeya`.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#irc

Comment: As a blind person I am not a fan of the stackexchange "chat" it works but it is very difficult to see

Comment: Also name change done

Answer (score 2):

[Yossi](/u/5079) has created the channel `##Mi-Yodeya` on [Freenode](//www.freenode.net/using_the_network.shtml).